# Changing default GRUB values in /etc/grub.d in archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, grub, grub2-mkconfig

I need some help with the grub configuration. I am trying to change some values in `/etc/default/grub` without changing it in that file, and adding the changes in a file in `/etc/grub.d/` directory

For example, i want to set `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` in a file named `/etc/grub.d/21_myconfig` so that it would be executed before `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` and enable `os-prober` when generating grub config file.

This is the contents of `/etc/grub.d/21_myconfig`

```
#!/bin/sh

export GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

But this does not work. Can you help me accomplish this?

The reason I am trying to change these values in `/etc/grub.d` and not in `/etc/default/grub` is that I am trying to create a `pacman` package for my grub configurations (So that I can install it in a fresh arch install without worrying about configuring it). But I am a little bit afraid to change `/etc/default/grub` with my package. So I try to install my configuration as a separate file `/etc/grub.d/21_myconfig`. Do you think packaging my configuration is a good idea?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making a package for your `21_myconfig` file but why not just copy `/etc/default/grub` whenever you make a fresh install?    That's kind of the point of that file, it's a place for you to put all your local settings.    BTW if 21_myconfig is the only file you need to add to /etc/grub.d, it's probably easier to just copy that when you need to, rather than make a package.

Comment: Alternatively, create a package that contains 21_myconfig *and* a sed or awk script that modifies /etc/default/grub and adds/changes/deletes the settings defined in it.

Comment: To disable `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` just remove the exec permission to prevent it running.